# Replace the jquery datepicker dateFormat with momentjs parsing and format

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker, momentjs

For the sake of consistency I would like to be able to switch the parsing/formatting of JQuery UI's datepicker to use momentjs instead.  Any thoughts on what might be the best way to do this?

Comment: one question : how it's working with empty values? Does it show broken calendar?

Comment: @demo refer to my comment below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500726/replace-the-jquery-datepicker-dateformat-with-momentjs-parsing-and-format?noredirect=1#comment68137293_24500727
if you want validation you can add it - it's very easy to do so too using the 'isValid' function of a moment.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

So far the best method that I've found to do this is to override the global **jquery-ui** `parseDate` and `formatDate` functions like so:

```
$.datepicker.parseDate = function(format, value) {
    return moment(value, format).toDate();
};
$.datepicker.formatDate = function (format, value) {
    return moment(value).format(format);
};
```

Then this nicely allows you to use the usual syntax for attaching a **datepicker** to a field but the format you specify will instead refer to a **momentjs** format instead http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

```
$(".selector").datepicker({ dateFormat: "MM-DD-YYYY" });
```

Comment: That's amazing! Way simpler than what others are [proposing around](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101603/how-do-i-convert-between-date-formats-used-by-jquery-ui-datepicker-and-moment-js). Thanks!

Comment: Nice solution but the 3rd parameter (settings parameter) is missing, thus parts of the datepicker functionality is lost.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy - the third options parameter applies only to how jQuery UI parses the date.  Since we're replacing the entire parse functionality with momentjs here it's not applicable.  eg momentjs is not going to understand { dayNamesShort: ["Dim", "Lun", "Mar", "Mer", "Jeu", "Ven", "Sam"] }.  You could perhaps write something to martial between the two if you really wanted, but you'd probably be better off changing these settings globally in momentjs: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/

Comment: This should be in their documents. Thank you for saving me another few hours.

Comment: But using this. The "higlighted days" function does not  work :/ (for me) - check: https://plnkr.co/edit/J1wzHTI3Ys28t1W4bRj8?p=preview

Comment: @Drasius - you're using a different date time picker entirely to the jquery UI one referred to in this question.  
jqueryUI Date Picker: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ your one: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/
You might want to email the owner of that Github repository to see if he can help you: https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker

Comment: Works great. However there was one instance where the datepicker popped up with an 'undefined/NaN' displayed all over! Removing the parseDate function fixed it.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde - the parseDate function is required for two way binding of the calendar and text field.  If you remove it and text is entered in the text input field then it will instead use jQuery mobile's default parseDate function which handles date formats very differently to momentjs.  The reason you observed undefined/NaN is most likely an invalid value was entered in the text field initially.  If you want to correctly avoid this, you could also add some error handling to the parseDate function by checking momentjs' isValid() function before calling toDate()

Comment: @Clint Aha. But I am not using jQuery Mobile, just the datepicker from jQuery UI, does it still matter? The date value I get is from an Ajax call to the server and we are basically trying to abstract the date rendering in the UI to be able to specify the format at one place. The date is already displayed in the UI using Moment, I just want to pick the date in the format Moment understands, so that we can later switch to Moment completely.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde - apologies, I meant jQueryUI.  My comment still applies to your issue - although it's not required until you want to switch everything to use moment completely (which I highly recommend you do now because it will save you a lot of issues if you're only working with a single datetime datatype).  To diagnose the issue I would debug whether moment(value, format).isValid() is true in the $.datepicker.parseDate function above.  If it's not true it means that moment has not been able to parse your initial string - note: moment allows you to specify multiple string patterns to parse

Answer (score 0):

If anyone using https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker plugin and facing the same issue, the first solution will be your take.
After using the accepted solution you will face selected date doesn't highlighted the issue.

So modifying accepted solution to fix selected date highlight issue

```
jQuery.datetimepicker.setDateFormatter({
  parseDate: function (date, format) {
    var d = moment(date, format);
    return d.isValid() ? d.toDate() : false;
  },
  formatDate: function (date, format) {
    if (format == "Y/m/d")
      return moment(date).year() + "/" + moment(date).month() + "/" + moment(date).date();
    return moment(date).format(format);
  }
});
```